# How could i append to list any output that my function gives, including errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, append

I want to apply my function `func` to a list of values and collect results. Sometimes it can output errors: JSONDecodeError, IndexError, etc.

A list to which i collect results is result_list. And if there is error, it also should be included.

So if i do:

```
for value in values_list:
   result_list.append(func(value))
```

and if there is error ( JSONDecodeError, IndexError, etc.) it should be appended to result_list

How could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using a `try-except` block. If you already know what errors will come up, it's best to catch those specific errors

```
for value in values_list:
    try:
        result_list.append(func(value))
    except (JSONDecodeError, IndexError) as err:
        result_list.append(str(err))
```

Alternatively, if you're unsure what possible errors could come up you could just do

```
for value in values_list:
    try:
        result_list.append(func(value))
    except Exception as err:
        result_list.append(str(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try-except, and if you only want to append the name of exception:

```
for value in values_list:
    try:
        result_list.append(func(value))
    except Exception as e:
        result_list.append(e.__class__.__name__)

# ['JSONDecodeError', 'IndexError', 'ValueError', 'TypeError']
```